# Different size of std::string::npos

Tags: c++, string

I wrote a program which finds a character in a string with use of the `find_last_of` method.

```
// ...
unsigned found;
found = name.find_last_of(character);
if (found == std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "NOT FOUND" << std::endl;
}
// ...
```

I've compiled the code on two machines, it works only on one of them (PC1). I've debugged it and found out, that std::string::npos is different for PC1 and PC2.

If no character is found then the value returned by the `find_last_of == 4294967295` for both machines.

PC1:

```
std::string::npos == 4294967295
```

PC2:

```
std::string::npos == 18446744073709551615
```

Some more tests:

PC1:

```
sizeof(size_t) == 4
```

PC2:

```
sizeof(size_t) == 8
```

First machine is using a 32-bit operating system, second one a 64-bit operating system.

What should I use to compare the value returned by the `find_last_of` method to make it work on both machines?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Compare it to `std::string::npos`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It wouldn't work if the type of `found`, namely `unsigned`, is too small to hold `std::string::npos`.

Comment: @hvd But why unsigned and not size_t?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There's no reason for that, it should be `size_t`. That's a bug in the code in the question, and the relevant bit of Karoly Horvath's answer. :)

Comment: @hvd that is a different issue: what type should I assign the result of `find_last_of` to.

Comment: I've used `unsigned` mostly because of the example I found here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Comment: @emilos [Don't trus cplusplus.com](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/)

Comment: @juanchopanza Sure. But just "Compare it to `std::string::npos`" is not really the best possible answer if the code in the question already compares it to `std::string::npos`, and it doesn't work. In that case, just looking a little bit further to see why it doesn't work (the wrong type for `found`), while indeed technically not required to answer the question, helps both the OP and others reading the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What should I use to compare the value returned by the find_last_of
>   method to make it work on both machines?

`std::string::npos`, and the type of the position (`found`) should be `size_t`.

The concrete size of the constant can be different on different architectures, but that is none of your concerns.

> npos is a static member constant value with the greatest possible
>   value for an element of type size_t.

Answer (score 4):

Just look at the function - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_last_of:

> size_type find_last_of( const basic_string& str, size_type pos = 0 ) const;   (1)
>   size_type find_last_of( const CharT* s, size_type pos, size_type count ) const; (2)
>   size_type find_last_of( const CharT* s, size_type pos = 0 ) const; (3)
>   size_type find_last_of( CharT ch, size_type pos = 0 ) const; (4)

Obviously, `std::string::size_type` is the proper type to store the return value in, after which comparison with `std::string::npos` will work.

Comment: Just to clarify, this doesn't contradict the other answer. `std::string::size_type` and `size_t` are the same type. `size_type` is more general, though, and also works in other cases where `(...)::size_type` is not `size_t`.